# Finding a tmux window where a pts belong

Tags: tmux

For some reason I seem to collect a lot of tmux windows (and browser tabs, but that's a different story). I have a process that is in the background of one of the windows, and I would like to find that window. I can see the process and its attached pts device in `ps`. Is there a way to find which pts device is associated to which window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, with the `list-panes` command.

```
tmux list-panes -a -F '#D #{pane_tty}'
%0 /dev/pts/9
%1 /dev/pts/10
```

You can use that to list many more things:

```
tmux list-panes -a -F '#D #T #{pane_tty} #{pane_current_command} #{pane_current_path}'
tmux list-windows -a -F '#{window_id} #W #{window_layout}' | while read w i; do echo $w $i; tmux list-panes -t "$w" -F "  #D #{pane_tty} #T #{pane_current_command}"; done
```

Look at the FORMATS section from the `tmux` man page.